# How does MapReduce read from multiple input files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr, emr

I am developing a code to read data and write it into `HDFS` using `mapreduce`. However when I have multiple files I don't understand how it is processed . The input path to the mapper is the name of the directory as evident from the output of

```
String filename = conf1.get("map.input.file");
```

So how does it process the files in the directory ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get the input file path you can use the `context` object, like this:

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
String inputFilePath = fileSplit.getPath().toString();
```

**And as for how it multiple files are processed:**

Several instances of the mapper function are created on the different machines in the cluster. Each instance receives a different input file. If files are bigger than the default dfs block size(128 MB) then files are further split into smaller parts and are then distributed to mappers.

So you can configure the input size being received by each mapper by following 2 ways:

- change the HDFS block size (eg `dfs.block.size=1048576`)
- set the paramaeter `mapred.min.split.size` (this can be only set to larger than HDFS block size)

**Note:**
These parameters will only be effective if your input format supports splitting the input files. Common compression codecs (such as gzip) don't support splitting the files, so these will be ignored.

Comment: Also you should mention that when we are dealing with gz files none of the configuration will work and each file will go to a single mapper and isn't split.

Comment: @Amar : Thanks for the detailed explanation. However , I am using a custom format and I have made my 'isSplitable()' false to read whole file into one mapper. And so to get the name of the file I tried using the 'FileStatus' object .

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to @Amar 's answer , I used FileStatus object in the following code as my customised inoput format would not split the input file.

```
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                FileStatus status= fs.getFileStatus(file);
                String fileName=status.getPath().toString();
```