# How does MapReduce process multiple input files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

So I'm writing a MR job to read hundreds of files from an input folder. Since all the files are compressed, so instead of using the default TextInputFormat, I was using the WholeFileReadFormat from an online code source.

So my question is that does the Mapper process multiple input files in sequence? I mean, if I have three files A B C, and since I'm reading the whole file content as the map input value, will mapreduce process the files in the order of, say, A->B->C, which means, only after doing with A, Mapper will start to process B?

Actually, I'm kind of confused on the concept of Map job and Map task. In my understanding the Map job is just the same thing as Mapper. And a mapper job contains several map tasks, in my case, each map task will read in a single file. But what I don't understand is that I think map tasks are executed in parallel, so I think all the input files should be processed in parallel, which turns out to be a paradox....

Can any one please explain it to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does MapReduce read from multiple input files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067129/how-does-mapreduce-read-from-multiple-input-files)